# Приходят на почту файлы как поврежденные?

Tags: php, файлы, form, fileupload

Есть код php обратная форма и приходят сообщения но файлы вложенные поврежденные.Кто нибудь может помочь в чем причина.Я не знаток языка PHP.И еще если кто откликнется буду благодарен еще за помощь как вписать чтоб можно файлы до максимума принимать.Мой код :

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
 if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];  
    $temp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  
    $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];

   $base = basename($file_name);
   $extension = substr($base, strlen($base)-4, strlen($base));

   //only these file types will be allowed
   $allowed_extensions = array("doc", "docx", "pdf", "zip", "png","jpeg","png","jpg");

   //check that this file type is allowed
   if(in_array($extension,$allowed_extensions)) {
       //mail essentials
       $from = $_POST['email'];
       $to = "k.komfo2@gmail.com";
       $subject = $_POST['name'];
       $message = $_POST['msg'];
       $phone = $_POST['phone'];

       //things u need
       $file = $temp_name;
       $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
       $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));  //unique identifier

       //standard mail headers
       $header = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
       $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto. "\r\n";
       $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";


       //declare multiple kinds of email (plain text + attch)
       $header .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n";
       $header .="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";

       //plain txt part

       $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
       $header .= $message. "\r\n";
       $header .= $phone. "\r\n";
       $header .= $subject. "\r\n";
       $header .= $message. "\r\n";

       //attch part
       $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
       $header .= $content."\r\n";  //chucked up 64 encoded attch


       //sending the mail - message is not here, but in the header in a multi part

       if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
        echo "Сообщение отправлено. Спасибо Вам " . $name . ", мы скоро свяжемся с Вами.Рекомендуем в случае задержки ответа обратиться по телефону ";
        echo "<br /><br /><a href='https://www.concept-comfort.com.ua'>Вернуться на сайт.</a>";

       }else {
           echo "Ошибка отправки";

       }


   }else {
       echo "файл не ушел"; }    //echo an html file
}else {
  echo " файл не прикрепился"; }    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Форма не закрыта. Попробуй заменить строку

```
$header .= $content."\r\n";  //chucked up 64 encoded attch
```

на

```
$header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";  //chucked up 64 encoded attch
$header .= "--".$uid."--";
```

Comment: Попробовал выдает ошибку файл не отправляется.Файл не ушел. это уведомление.Что еще предложите?

Comment: @Sandero `$extension = pathinfo($base,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` чтоб получить расширение файлов правильно. В случае с `$extension = substr($base, strlen($base)-4, strlen($base));` отрезается последние 4 символа (в `file.docx` -  это будет `docx`, а в файле `file.doc` - это `.doc`). До отправки письма скрипт не дошел.

Comment: $extension = substr($base,  strlen($base)) так мне так оставить?

Comment: лучше так `$extension = pathinfo($base,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: Попробовал.В общем вместо Header если не добавлять файл приходит но поврежден.А с Хедером концом Ошибки выдает при отравки